# $k$-th number in $N \times M$ Table

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Given an array $A$ , where $A[i][j] = i\times j$ and $1 \leq  i \leq N, 1 \leq j \leq M$ , then what is the best way to find the $k$-th number in this array , if we order them into a single array in increasing value ?

Comment: Are you counting repeated values?

Comment: Yes repeated values are taken into account

Comment: My first thought is to find a function $n(p)$ that returns the number of entries less than or equal to $p$, then binary search.  For $M,N$ large $n(p) \approx pH_p \approx p (\ln p +0.577)$  where $H_p$ is the $p^{\text{th}}$ harmonic number.  There is a correction if $p \gt M,N$

Comment: $n(p)$ can be found in $O(M)$ or $O(N)$ complexity .

Answer (score 2):

A really interesting question. I thought that it should be possible to write this in "closed form" - here meaning that it should be possible to compute it in *constant* time. I did not manage to do so, but still think that it *might* be possible - maybe based on [A000005](http://oeis.org/A000005), [A061017](http://oeis.org/A061017), or the derived ones like [A006218](http://oeis.org/A006218)...

Until someone finds such a closed form: Each value $a$ appears in the matrix when it can be written as $a = i\cdot j$ with $i \leq N$ and $j \leq M$. The idea is now to count the *number* of divisors $i,j$ of each value $a = 1 ... k$ that satisfy this criterion (the $k$ here is just an upper bound). These numbers will be summed up, until the sum is greater than or equal to $k$. The current $a$ is then the value we have been looking for.

The asymptotic running time of this should be $\mathcal{O}(kM)$.

Here is the the brute force solution (with sorting) and the solution by counting the divisors, implemented in Java, for those who are interested.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class KthEntryTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (int N=1; N<=10; N++)
        {
            for (int M=1; M<=10; M++)
            {
                for (int k=1; k<=M*N; k++)
                {
                    int resultA = computeBruteForce(N, M, k);
                    int resultB = computeByCount(N, M, k);
                    System.out.println("N="+N+", M="+M+", k="+k+", resultA="+resultA+", resultB="+resultB);
                    if (resultA != resultB)
                    {
                        System.out.println("ERROR!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int computeBruteForce(int N, int M, int k)
    {
        int A[][] = new int[N][M];
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=M; j++)
            {
                A[i-1][j-1] = i*j;
            }
        }
        int a[] = flatten(A); 
        Arrays.sort(a);
        return a[k-1];
    }


    private static int[] flatten(int A[][])
    {
        int N = A.length;
        int M = A[0].length;
        int result[] = new int[N*M];
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            System.arraycopy(A[i], 0, result, i*M, M);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int computeByCount(int N, int M, int k)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<=k; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j=1; j<=M; j++)
            {
                if (i%j == 0)
                {
                    int d = i/j;
                    if (d <= N)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            sum += count;
            if (sum >= k)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting Problem :) 
We can solve it using binary search as [Ross Milikan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1827/ross-millikan) indicated. 
The main thing left is to find $n(p)$ which can be done simply in $O(M)$ complexity ,
where 
$$n(p) = \sum_{i=1}^M min(floor(p/i),N)$$

The logic used over here is to find count of elements less than or equal to $p$ in $jth$ column , which will be equivalent to $min(floor(p,i),N)$ .

This comes from the fact that the number multiples of $i$ less than equal to $p$ is equal to $floor(p,i)$ and we take minimum since a column can contain at maximum $N$ elements.

So , we can solve this in $O(M log (NM))$ .

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* to anyone who has more time than me: it would appear that if $A[i][j]$ is the $k$-th term then the $(k+1)$-th term is a neighbour of $A[i][j]$. In which case it may be possible to do this in $\mathcal{O}(k)$ using a recursive algorithm.

---

That failing, here's a naive solution:

- Construct $\tilde{A}$ which is the upper-left $\min(N,k)\times\min(M,k)$ matrix of $A$.
- Sort $\tilde{A}$ into the single array $B$.
- [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) $B$.
- Pick the $k$-th element of ordered $B$.

The bottleneck is the quicksort which is, on average, $\mathcal{O}(NM\log(NM))$.

Comment: We can also binary search for the value .

Comment: You don't have the terms neighboring.  For example, $21=3 \cdot 7$ is not a neighbor of $22=2 \cdot 11$.  There are many examples.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically selection in a Young's tableaux, and also selection in X+Y sorted SUM matrix (taking $X[i] = Y[i] = \log i$, the sums being $S[i,j] = \log i + \log j$), the latter of which has known $O(M+N)$ time algorithms for selecting the $k^{th}$ largest element.

This paper: [Generalize Selection and Ranking: Sorted Matrices](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0213002) has an $O(M+N)$ time algorithm for sorted sums selection.

An explanation of that algorithm (called the FJ-Algorithm, for the initials of the authors of the above paper) can be found in section 2 of this paper: [Cache oblivious selection in sorted X+Y matrices](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.0936.pdf).